# Does this match your definition of a Listener Object?

Tags: javascript, oop, definition, listener

## Overview:

In my project, all of the **UI Components** that are rendered in DOM/HTML, are stored/managed as Javascript objects of type **Component**.

Each **Component** Object contains a **ComponentListener** class which listens for events coming from the **DOM/HTML rendering**, and also *listens* for **events** *fired* to the **Component** that it might receive from the **EventController**.

The **EventController** is just another Javascript class that implements a *centralized* **Publisher/Subscriber Pattern** (or if you prefer, a *centralized* **Subject/Observer Pattern**)...*to promote decoupling.*

The *ComponentListener* is given the definition below:

## Definition:

An object that receives events for its parent component-object,  from **managed elements** in the **DOM** (that are managed by the parent component-object), or from the **EventController**.

## For Example:

An instance of **ComponentListener** that might have its **onMouseEnter** method that will be called when the mouse enters the <div> element that represents the component-object that it is listening to events for.

## Question:

Does my definition of the ComponentListener warrent being defined as another term rather than Listener?  Or am I about **"spot on"** defining it as ComponentListener?

Comment: I think ComponentListner is a good name.

Answer (score 0):

Listeners listens to **events**, not components. Components generate events. If you search for event listeners I am sure you will find interesting material.

Comment: Okay so listeners listen to events...the events I'm talking about come from the DOM elements, a.k.a. the HTML representation of the UI component which is managed by a JS object which contains a ComponentListener.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. "An object that receives events" is a listener, it usually gets the component that raised the event as parameter. That is a good definition. "a component-object from the DOM or from the EventController" seems to be your specific example.

Comment: I just edited my question again for clarification...I don't think I was clear enough last time.